# What does CTRL + ALT + F11 do and why did this solve my problems with disappearing menu bars?

Tags: windows-10

I have this strange problem that some applications and folder views loose the menu bar. There is nothing wrong with the main window, I can type, select, edit what ever, but when I click on the menu bar - either a item like 'file' or the top bar where the closing 'X' resides - windows behaves as if I clicked on the program underneath it. Sometimes the menu bar is completely grey, but sometimes I see it normally but it is like a ghost.

I accidentally discovered that - at least for a folder view - it is solved when I press CTRL + ALT + F11. Why?

I have this problem occasionally the last few weeks.

Comment: `CTRL+ALT+F11` set the File Explorer window to full screen

Comment: That is only F11 or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes;  Which means `CTRL+ALT+F11` isn't actually supposed to do anything, in fact, it does nothing, and Windows is simply capturing the F11.  If it does anything put place the File Explorer window to full screen then it's provided by a third-party application.

Comment: But using only F11 alone does not fix my lost menu bar, CTRL + F11 or ALT + F11 has also not that effect; only CTRL + ALT + F11

Comment: The shortcut by default doesn’t do anything on my system, it’s simply picking up, F11 on my system.  So you clearly have an unidentied third-party application that is picking it up that does do something

Answer (score 3):

Now I have found the function of Ctrl+Alt+F11 on my W10Home.
The PC has INTEL UHD Graphics 630.
The change between scaling-options is done by this key-combination.
This Function can be optional switched off, if so, this key-Combination is free for other applications.